# Running count of repeating values by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and got stuck, appreciate any help.

I have the following dataset:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,320], [1,1,320], [1,1,320], [1,1,320], [1,1,319], [1,1,319], [1,1,319], [1,1,319], [1,2,319], [1,2,319], [1,2,319]]), columns = ['PortID', 'FuelGroupID', 'Price'])

    PortID  FuelGroupID  Price
0        1            1    320
1        1            1    320
2        1            1    320
3        1            1    320
4        1            1    319
5        1            1    319
6        1            1    319
7        1            1    319
8        1            2    319
9        1            2    319
10       1            2    319
```

For each PortID and FuelGroupID i'm trying to have a running count of repeating values - the count should break if there is a value change.

I've been able to achieve the count by using this code:

```
df.groupby((df['Price'] != df['Price'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

However, this applies the logic to the entire dataset while i want the count to reset for each new combination of PortID and FuelGroupID

So the expected output should be

```
    PortID  FuelGroupID  Price Count
0        1            1    320     0
1        1            1    320     1
2        1            1    320     2
3        1            1    320     3
4        1            1    319     0
5        1            1    319     1
6        1            1    319     2
7        1            1    319     3
8        1            2    319     0
9        1            2    319     1
10       1            2    319     2
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) or [`np.not_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.not_equal.html) then use [`pd.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) and [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) here.

```
s = df.ne(df.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
# s = np.not_equal(df, df.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
df['Count'] = s.groupby(s).cumcount()

    PortID  FuelGroupID  Price  Count
0        1            1    320      0
1        1            1    320      1
2        1            1    320      2
3        1            1    320      3
4        1            1    319      0
5        1            1    319      1
6        1            1    319      2
7        1            1    319      3
8        1            2    319      0
9        1            2    319      1
10       1            2    319      2
```

Answer (score 1):

you are close, since you want to work per `PortID` and `FuelGroupID`, you should wrap your code in a groupby:

```
groups = df.groupby(['PortID','FuelGroupID'])['Price']

group1 = groups.ngroup()
group2 = groups.apply(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

df['new_col'] = df.groupby([group1, group2]).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
    PortID  FuelGroupID  Price  new_col
0        1            1    320        0
1        1            1    320        1
2        1            1    320        2
3        1            1    320        3
4        1            1    319        0
5        1            1    319        1
6        1            1    319        2
7        1            1    319        3
8        1            2    319        0
9        1            2    319        1
10       1            2    319        2
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The count should re-set on line 8 as FuelGroupID changes

Comment: @Anton1990 thanks for pointing that out. updated the answer.

Comment: thank you this code works; I marked the other solution as solved the problem with fewer lines of code.